# Double count within a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table users:

```
user_id    name
1          John
2          Dan
3          Jane
4          Sophie
5          Jodie
```

I then have a table named associates:

```
user_id    assoc_id
1          2
1          3 
3          4
3          1
3          5
4          1
5          1
5          2
```

What I want to do is show how many associates each user has, or none

So, the results would show

```
user_id    Name     Number of Associates
1          John     2
2          Dan      0
3          Jane     3
4          Sophie   1
5          Jodie    2
```

What I'm trying works but does not show those with 0

Here's what I'm trying, how do I get the 0s?

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.name, count(a.user_id) as howmany from users u
join associates a on a.user_id = u.user_id
group by u.user_id order by u.user_id asc
```

Comment: Found a useful service here on SO pages: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e9577/4 - your question and the obvious answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.name, count(a.user_id) as howmany 
FROM users u LEFT OUTER JOIN associates a 
ON a.user_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id 
ORDER BY u.user_id ASC
```

The `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will include every rows of the first table even is they aren't present in the joined table.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
    SELECT u.user_id, 
    u.name, 
    count(a.user_id) as howmany 
    FROM users u 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN associates a 
    ON a.user_id = u.user_id
    GROUP BY u.user_id 
    ORDER BY u.user_id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a left join instead of a inner join, that should select the rows that do not have corresponding associates.

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.name, count(a.user_id) as howmany 
from users u
left join associates a 
  on a.user_id = u.user_id
group by u.user_id 
order by u.user_id asc
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work with strict rules also (if i had not made any typo):

```
SELECT   users.*, ISNULL(associatesCount.AssocCount, 0) AS AssocCount
FROM    users
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS AssocCount
        FROM associates
        GROUP BY user_id
        ) AS associatesCount
        ON users.user_id = associatesCount.user_id
```